# AttributeError: __enter__: requests.get Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse this site: https://decrypt.co/14493/the-12-dapps-of-christmas and get a title. However I get a `AttributeError: __enter__` error on line `with requests.get(url) as urlobj:`.

```
    def get_title(self, url):
        # gets the title of the article from the web
        print("get_title url: " + url)  //get_title url: https://decrypt.co/14493/the-12-dapps-of-christmas
        with requests.get(url) as urlobj:  //error here
            soup = bs(urlobj.content, "html.parser")
            title = soup.find("h1", class_="Headings__H1-sc-1ibq1fi-0 PostHeader__Heading-sc-1cg3u6k-4 fXgBJm").text
            title = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")
            return title
```

My requirements.txt:

```
requests==2.22.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
Flask==1.1.1
flask_wtf==0.14.2
praw==6.4.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

```
py -3.6 -m pip list
```

gives this result:

[image]

and I run the program from PyCharm's Python3.6 interpreter or with `py -3.6 TelegramBot.py` command.

**EDIT**:

I update requests and now get

```
    title = soup.find("h1", class_="Headings__H1-sc-1ibq1fi-0 PostHeader__Heading-sc-1cg3u6k-4 fXgBJm").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

error on

```
title = soup.find("h1", class_="Headings__H1-sc-1ibq1fi-0 PostHeader__Heading-sc-1cg3u6k-4 fXgBJm").text
```

Does it mean it couldn't find the object with a specified class?

Comment: You may be using an old version of the library that doesn't support its `Response` objects being used in a context manager?

Comment: At the very least, you don't have the latest version. Try updating.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please see edit

Comment: That's a separate error that has been answered numerous times. You'll find many answers if you search. In short, `find` didn't find the result you wanted.

Comment: @parsecer check my answer below.

Comment: If you claim that there are answers, show link plz, this is thread google shows on searching: AttributeError: __enter__ requests ... this version of requests doesnt support the syntax, should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://decrypt.co/14493/the-12-dapps-of-christmas")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("h2", {'class': 'sc-kpOJdX bgcxqD'}):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
1. MyCrypto Heroes
2. Arcane Maps
3. ForkDelta
4. Synthetix
5. Photo Vault
6. NewDex
7. Compound
8. Dice
9. RocketGame
10. Maker
11. Crypto Legends
12. Graphite Docs
```